# C++/CLI: Compiling static library with /CLR support

Tags: .net, clr, c++-cli, static-libraries

We have old (working) code that consists of a static library compiled with /CLR, and a C++/CLI DLL that links to the static lib. We are about to add new features to this static lib.

Now, I've have heard from numerous sources that CLR static libraries are not supported by Microsoft, and therefore I'm pushing to clean this up and switch to DLL before we start adding new features to this project. However, I haven't been able to find any official information from Microsoft regarding this (say, from MSDN - other than their forums).

I will appreciate any resources about this whole "static lib with CLR" issue.

Comment: Well, we ended up converting this static library to a DLL anyway. We are happier now.

Comment: Last time I tried this the linker rejected the lib with an error message, it will probably depend on the content though. If I remember right the scenarios which work and which don't were documented somewhere in the linker docs.

Comment: http://gumdroplab.blogspot.com/2007/08/linking-to-ccli-static-libraries.html